# How to adjust Amchart Balloon Size

Tags: javascript, amcharts

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R2Hj.png

Hi,

I'm trying to add a line chart with 3 different graphs. The graph rendering is working just fine but the balloons are very unbalanced (see the picture), thus invalid for production usage. It does not help if I add horizontal or vertical paddings.

I must be doing something wrong here but I cannot figure out what it is. Would anyone figure out the reason for the odd balloon behaviour?

```html
       var chart3 = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv3", {
                    "type": "serial",
                    "theme": "light",
                    "marginRight": 20,
                    "marginLeft": 50,
                    "autoMarginOffset": 20,
                    "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
                    
                    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
                    "chartCursor": {
                        "fullWidth": true,
                        "valueLineEnabled": true,
                        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
                        "valueLineAlpha": 0.5,
                        "cursorAlpha": 0
                    },
                    "valueAxes": [{
                        "id": "v1",
                        "axisAlpha": 0,
                        "position": "left"
                    }],
                    "balloon": {
                        "borderThickness": 1,
                        "shadowAlpha": 0
                    },
                    "graphs": [{
                        "id": "g1",
                        "balloon": {                            
                            "adjustBorderColor": false,
                            "color": "#ffffff",
                            "horizontalPadding": 20,
                            "verticalPadding": 20

                        },
                            
       
                        "dashLength": 3,
                        "bullet": "round",
                        "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
                        
                        "bulletSize": 6,
                        "hideBulletsCount": 100,
                        "lineThickness": 2,
                        "title": "received",
                        "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
                        "valueField": "Value",
                        "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:16px;'>[[Value]]</span>"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "g2",
                        "balloon": {                            
                            "adjustBorderColor": false,
                            "color": "#ffffff"
                        },
                        "bullet": "round",
                        "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
                        "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
                        "bulletSize": 5,
                        "hideBulletsCount": 50,
                        "lineThickness": 2,
                        "title": "red line",
                        "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
                        "valueField": "Value2",
                        "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:12px;'>[[Value2]]</span>"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "g3",
                        "balloon": {                    
                            "adjustBorderColor": false,
                            "color": "#ffffff"
                        },
                        "bullet": "round",
                        "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
                        "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
                        "bulletSize": 5,
                        "hideBulletsCount": 50,
                        "lineThickness": 2,
                        "title": "red line",
                        "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
                        "valueField": "Value3",
                        "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:12x;'>[[Value3]]</span>"
                    }],
                    "chartScrollbar": {
                        "graph": "g1",
                        "oppositeAxis": false,
                        "offset": 30,
                        "scrollbarHeight": 80,
                        "backgroundAlpha": 0,
                        "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
                        "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
                        "graphFillAlpha": 0,
                        "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
                        "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
                        "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
                        "autoGridCount": true,
                        "color": "#AAAAAA"
                    },
                    "chartCursor": {
                        "pan": true,
                        "valueLineEnabled": true,
                        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
                        "cursorAlpha": 1,
                        "cursorColor": "#258cbb",
                        "limitToGraph": "g1",
                        "valueLineAlpha": 0.2,
                        "valueZoomable": true
                    },
                    "categoryField": "Date",
                    "categoryAxis": {
                        "parseDates": true,
                        "dashLength": 1,
                        "minorGridEnabled": true,                       
                    "dateFormats":
                        [
                { period: 'fff', format: 'JJ:NN:SS' },
                        {period:'ss',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
                        {period:'mm',format:'JJ:NN'},
                        {period:'hh',format:'JJ:NN'},
                        {period:'DD',format:'MMM DD'},
                        {period:'WW',format:'MMM DD'},
                        {period:'MM',format:'MM'},
                        {period: 'YYYY', format: 'YYYY' }
                ]
                    },
                    "export": {
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    "dataProvider": Home.realizedReturnsChartItems
                });
             
            }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this on my end: https://jsfiddle.net/brb65Lgy/ Perhaps you have some CSS on your end that is conflicting? Can you update the fiddle to reproduce your screenshot?